# Transfer NFT minted via Metaplex(candy machine)

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

Does the minted NFT from Metaplex(candy machine) automatically generate the Token Account (as I am planning to transfer it to other owner via Javascript). Also, i am using the function getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount to create a token account but my problem is it needs keypair and I dont know where to locate if I a only have a wallet address? Here is my code:

```
   // wallet address of the owner of NFT but I want to get the keypair here since it is the one that is required for getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount
    const fromWallet = owner_wallet;
    // Public Key of buyer
    const toWallet = buyer_wallet;
   // NFT mint address
   let mint = mint_address;
   //connection
   const connection = use_connection;

   // Get the token account of the toWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
        const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, fromWallet, mint, toWallet);

  // Get the token account of the fromWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it (my problem here is 2nd parameter is looking for keypair but i can only provide a wallet address
  const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        fromWallet,
        mint,
        fromWallet.publicKey
    );

  const signature = await transfer(
        connection,
        fromWallet,
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        0
    );
    console.log(`finished transfer with ${signature}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

- Does the minted NFT from Metaplex(candy machine) automatically generate the Token Account --> Yes
- (as I am planning to transfer it to other owner via Javascript) --> you need / should create a new token account and not just transfer the ownership of the token account
- Also, i am using the function getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount to create a token account but my problem is it needs keypair and I dont know where to locate if I a only have a wallet address?  --> You need to use the wallet / keypair of the wallet that is the current holder of the NFT.

This question is not related to candy machine but to transferring NFTs. Have a look here to learn how to transfer tokens: https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-spl-tokens

Comment: thank you for the swift answer, sorry I am new to blockchain thing. 

1st: Can I use the Token Account here for the owner side? Or What? I am not sure what is the optimized and standard way  to send and NFT so a good advise is welcome
2nd: Correct me if I am wrong, So I create a new token account and add the mint address there? This means create a new keypair?
3rd: now I am Confuse here? Basically all i wanted is to transfer the NFT to another wallet.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is too late to answer but I will just put it here in case anyone needs them.
I assume you are using a connected wallet for this from the frontend. So what you need to do is:

```
TOKEN_PUBLIC_KEY = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(TOKEN_PUBLIC_KEY); // NFT Mint Address
RECEIVER_PUBLIC_KEY = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(OWNER_PUBLIC_KEY); // Address of the receiver of the NFT 
const receiverTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
  TOKEN_PUBLIC_KEY,
  RECEIVER_PUBLIC_KEY
);
const oAccountInfo = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(ATA);
// This is a check if the receiver already has an associated account for storing the token if not it will create one first.
if (oAccountInfo.value == null) {
  const tx = new anchor.web3.Transaction().add(
    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      wallet.publicKey,
      receiverTokenAccount,
      wallet.publicKey,
      TOKEN_PUBLIC_KEY
    )
  );
  await sProvider.sendAndConfirm(tx); // This will send the transaction with your connected wallet as signer
}
```

Replace this with your `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` function you won't need a keypair but ya you need a connected wallet.

Also you have to use instructions for transfer of SPL-token.